# JQuery input value number and decimal only

Tags: jquery

I want input field accept numbers and decimal only.

Input field should not accept negative, letters, symbols other than single decimal.
Number 1 works absolutely fine with input type "text".
However, number 2 doesn't work and the only difference is type as number.

I want numbers and decimals only. No negative, no letter and no symbol.

Comment: check this answer...exactly what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36692091/jquery-input-value-number-and-decimal-only/36692958#36692958

Answer (score 1):

All the keyboard keys have different ASCII code just creating a script which will except only number and decimals by recognising there acsii codes rest will be ignored

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="inputNumberDot">
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.inputNumberDot').keypress(function(event) {
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode

    if (
      (charCode != 45 || $(this).val().indexOf('-') != -1) && // “-” CHECK MINUS, AND ONLY ONE.
      (charCode != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && // “.” CHECK DOT, AND ONLY ONE.
      (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
      return false;

    return true;

  });
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/Luaq2f65/2/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#decimal').keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(isNaN(val)){
         val = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
         if(val.split('.').length>2) 
             val =val.replace(/\.+$/,"");
    }
    $(this).val(val); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="decimal"min="0" max="10" step="0.25" value="0.00" />
```

Add ID like this in input,

```
<p>
number 2(input type="number") <input id="decimal" type="number" onchange="Numeric(this.event)" />
</p>
```

**Js:**
    var pastValue, pastSelectionStart, pastSelectionEnd;

```
$("input").on("keydown", function() {
    pastValue          = this.value;
    pastSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
    pastSelectionEnd   = this.selectionEnd;
}).on("input propertychange", function() {
    var regex = /^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/;

    if (this.value.length > 0 && !regex.test(this.value)) {
        this.value          = pastValue;
        this.selectionStart = pastSelectionStart;
        this.selectionEnd   = pastSelectionEnd;
    }

});

      $('#decimal').keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(isNaN(val)){
         val = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
         if(val.split('.').length>2) 
             val =val.replace(/\.+$/,"");
    }
    $(this).val(val); 
});
```

Comment: Doesnt work. I have put your provided solution on jsfiddle and it doesnt work for decimal. I want numbers and decimals only. No negative, no letter and no symbol.
[http://jsfiddle.net/f1w38jw0/110/]

Comment: dude, i couldn't edit your JsFiddler try to paste the code in your fiddler.

Comment: Thanks Prabhat. the new solutions given by you doesnt work for decimal values.

Comment: But now the input type is text. I want to make it working with type number.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Using ID, you can use class for generic solution.

```
     $('.inputclassname').on('keypress', function(e){
     return e.metaKey || // cmd/ctrl
     e.which <= 0 || // arrow keys
     e.which == 8 || // delete key
     /[0-9]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which)); // numbers
     })
```

Comment: Doesnt work. I have put your provided solution on jsfiddle and it doesnt work for decimal. I want numbers and decimals only. No negative, no letter and no symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get value from `<input type="number" />` if its not valid (if it contains letters). Every time when you are trying to access `this.value.length` it equals to `""`. Because of that your `if` statement never reached.

If you need to accept only digits, you need to check `keyCode` before input, and return false if `keyCode` does not match digit or arrow keys or delete or backspace:

```js
$("input").on("keydown", function(e) {
    var charCode = e.which;

    return !!(
            (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57)
            || (charCode >= 37 && charCode <= 40)
            || (charCode >= 96 && charCode <= 105)
            || charCode == 17
            || charCode == 13
            || charCode == 46
            || charCode == 8
            || charCode == 9
            || charCode == 188

    )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" min="0" step="0.1" />
```

Comment: No. Doesnt match the requirement. please read the specification.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Chrome has disabled the select API for inputs of type number and email as found [here](https://github.com/KevinSheedy/jquery.alphanum/issues/19) so you are looking for a workaround cause this code will not work.

> Hi
>
> The Chrome browser recently disabled the select api for inputs of type
>   number and email: https://codereview.chromium.org/100433008/#ps60001
>
> The select api is a collection of attributes and functions that allow
>   us to get and set which portion of text a user has highlighted in an
>
> The attributes and functions in question are: select() selectionStart
>   selectionEnd selectionDirection setRangeText() setSelectionRange()

Check your jsfiddle console and you can find what the error is exactly about:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionStart'
>   property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('number')
>   does not support selection.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution for simple jquery is

**HTML**

`<input type="text" id="amount" class="decimal" placeholder="Enter Amount">`

**Jquery**

```
$(function(){
  $("input.decimal").bind("change keyup input", function () {
    var position = this.selectionStart - 1;
    //remove all but number and .
    var fixed = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
    if (fixed.charAt(0) === '.') //can't start with .
      fixed = fixed.slice(1);

    var pos = fixed.indexOf(".") + 1;
    if (pos >= 0) //avoid more than one .
      fixed = fixed.substr(0, pos) + fixed.slice(pos).replace('.', '');

    if (this.value !== fixed) {
      this.value = fixed;
      this.selectionStart = position;
      this.selectionEnd = position;
    }
  });
});
```

Working Example: [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cdr9tLjw/1/)

Comment: This works better than most solutions I've found, but I can't quite get it to stay at 2 decimal points. `parseFloat(fixed).toFixed(2)` causes odd behavior.